# I want to increase the Real Time Reporting API request limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are using the Core Reporting API and Real Time Reporting API.

This API limit 10000request/day per view, but I want to increase the this

Is this possible?
if possible, please let me know how we can increase quota limits and the price for the case of 20000 request/day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several quotas for the Google Analytics APIs and Google APIs in general.

- requests/day   0 of 50,000
- requests/100seconds/user    100
- requests/perView    10000

Your application can make 50000 requests per day by default.  This can be extended but it takes a while to get permission when you are getting close to this limit around 80% its best to request an extension at that time.

Your user can max make 100 requests a second which must be something that has just gone up last I knew it was only 10 requests a second.  User is denoted by IP address.  There is no way to extend this quota more then the max you cant apply for it or pay for it.

Then there is the last quota the one you asked about. You can make max 10000 requests a day to a view.  This isn't just application based if the user runs my application and your application then together we have only 10000 requests that can be made.  This quota is a pain if you ask me.   Now for the bad news there is no way to extend this quota you cant apply for it you cant pay for it and you cant beg the Google Analytics dev team (I have tried)

**Answer**:  No you cant extend the per view per day quota limit.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
I will put up with requests/perView 10000.

Comment: It resets at midnight west cost usa time.   Because you are using the realtime api you just need to calculate how much you can request. If you hit the quota not even googles official android app will work for the rest of the day.  I have been working with the team for a few years trying to explain to them why they should fix this quota.  I am going to forward your question to them so they can see others having a problem