# Audit Report API Limit Increase

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I need to access Google Docs Audit Activity for my domain. The limit for the same is 1000 records in a single API call. Also, the number of API calls per day is 10K.
What is the way to increase the limits for API calls per day? Google Support is unable to answer this question and redirected me to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563257/i-want-to-increase-the-real-time-reporting-api-request-limit) regarding quota increase for Report API:

> There are several quotas for the Google Analytics APIs and Google APIs in general.
>
> - requests/day   0 of 50,000
> - requests/100seconds/user    100
> - requests/perView    10000
>
> Your application can make 50000 requests per day by default.  This can be extended but it takes a while to get permission when you are getting close to this limit around 80% its best to request an extension at that time.
>
> Your user can max make 100 requests a second which must be something that has just gone up last I knew it was only 10 requests a second.  User is denoted by IP address.  There is no way to extend this quota more then the max you cant apply for it or pay for it.
>
> Then there is the last quota the one you asked about. You can make max 10000 requests a day to a view.  This isn't just application based if the user runs my application and your application then together we have only 10000 requests that can be made.  This quota is a pain if you ask me.   Now for the bad news there is no way to extend this quota you cant apply for it you cant pay for it and you cant beg the Google Analytics dev team (I have tried)
>
> **Answer**:  No you cant extend the per view per day quota limit.

If you encountered error, it is recommended to catch the exception and, using an [exponential backoff](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_binary_exponential_backoff) algorithm, wait for a small delay before retrying the failed call.